# Searching within returned element

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have code like so to gather information about all item listings on a page and return them:

```
const resultsArr = await page.$$eval('.result-row', elements =>
  elements.map(el => {
    return {
      price: await page.eval('how do I search within the element el?')
    }
  })
);
```

Testing in the chrome console I can get the elements and do something like

```
elements[0].find('.result-price')[0].innerHTML // returns '$1,500'
```

I am having a hard time translating my jquery into puppeteer. The question is, in the above example, how can I search and return data from element `el`?

Comment: Nested `page` functions are impossible because `eval` callbacks are run in the browser, and `page` isn't a thing there. You're probably confusing what's executing within the browser console and what's executing within Node. Use native browser functions like `document.querySelector` to search within an `eval` block -- the same code you run in the console should work. If you wouldn't mind sharing the website and context about what you're trying to accomplish exactly, I can provide a less hand-wavey answer.

Comment: thank you @ggorlen, I will look to use native browser functions here. The answer I accepted solved it that way and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [page.evaluate](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

```
const resultsArr = await page.evaluate(() => {

    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result-row .result-price')).map(el => {

        return {
            price: el.innerText
        };

    });
});
```

Comment: That code works perfectly. Thank you.